# Can some one tell me what this is doing?

Tags: c#

```
                for (j = 0;j < recipe.Count; j++)
```

> recipe is a  list

```
                {

                    for (i = 0;  i < 9; i++) 
                    {

                        if (recipe[j] == tempFoodname)
                        {

                            for (int k = 2; j < 9; j++)
                            {

                                nutOneH[k] += double.Parse(nutrientArray[i, k]) * (nutrientListGram[j] / grams);
```

> nutrient array is a huge array that carries a lot of data that is read
>   from a text file

```
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                for (int k = 2; j < 9; j++)
                {

                    nutServe[k] = nutOneH[k] * (servings / 100);
                }
```

Comment: Read up about [step by step debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

It is iterating over the lists of recipes:

```
 for (j = 0;j < recipe.Count; j++)
```

looking for the right one:

```
if (recipe[j] == tempFoodname)
```

It also does something with the `nutrientArray[i, k]`, which is a 2-dimensional array. And I have to say, I really hate those. They are just a pain to iterate over. I prefer jagged arrays every day of the week.

Just based on the names, I would say it is trying to figure out the "nutrients for one Helping" (`nutOneH`), which happens to be a array. But I can not figure out that formula at all:

```
nutOneH[k] += double.Parse(nutrientArray[i, k]) * (nutrientListGram[j] / grams);
```

And this one seems plain broken. It initialize k, uses k in the loops - but counts up j. The formula seems about figuring out "Nutrients from one Serving" from the one per helpings? Apparently 1 helping is 100 servings and you need the proper fraction based on actual servings requested?

```
for (int k = 2; j < 9; j++)
{
    nutServe[k] = nutOneH[k] * (servings / 100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense